# How I create or update postgresql sequence with variable

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I'm tring to create or update postgresql sequence with variable

If I put exact value when I create or update sequence, It works

like create sequence test minvalue 5 maxvalue 10 start 5;

but If I create some function which set min and maxvalue of sequence like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(bigint, bigint)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    create sequence test minvalue $1 maxvalue $2 start $1;
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
```

It makes errors

I'm searching to find the way to put the variable when I create sequence

who knows the way? please help.

I just want to create sequence range

Answer (score 5):

You might need to use dynamic SQL, for that kind if statement.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Don't forget to quote_ident() and quote_literal() as needed.